# Looping in JasperReports

Tags: jasper-reports

Is there a way to do a single line loop in a TextField expression? I know that it allows for ternary operations, but what about loops.

For example if I wanted a series of numbers of five numbers after a given field, in the detail, how would you display that?

**For example**

```
 The field b has a value of 4. How would you make it print out [inside a Text field] 4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution to this is to create a scriptlet. There is no functionality inside the expressions that would allow for a loop.